# The difference between "reviewed by" and "communicated by"

Tags: publications

I´d seen the phrase "Reviewed by (someone)" and also the phrase "Communicated by (someone)" in published papers, what they refer to or the difference(s) between them?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of a journal listing "reviewed by"? Do they perhaps have open peer review? For the other phrase, see [Article “communicated by”](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7645/17254).

Comment: @Anyon, thanks for your comment, in fact, one can see on mathscinet  database in the description of an article between brackets reviewed by XYZ